# ERROR in @types/ws trying to update from angular 12 to angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular12, angular13

I have updated my project from angular 12 to angular 13 and I'm facing this error:

```
Error: node_modules/@types/ws/index.d.ts:328:18 - error TS2315: Type 'Server' is not generic.

328         server?: HTTPServer<V> | HTTPSServer<V> | undefined;
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@types/ws/index.d.ts:328:34 - error TS2315: Type 'Server' is not generic.

328         server?: HTTPServer<V> | HTTPSServer<V> | undefined;
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried installing `npm i @types/ws` with no success.

Answer (score 34):

Solution: npm install -f @types/ws@8.5.4

Answer (score 2):

I just had to update "@types/node". The *problematic* version I had installed was v12

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading `@types/ws` to 8.5.4 as mentioned above was strangely not the fix - I already had that version.
However, this tip by @vidalsasoon was more helpful, even though I was using Node 16 by now, I still had `@types/node` version 12 (I guess it just worked) - I needed to update to 18 since I'm now on Node 18:

```bash
npm i @types/node@18
```

This fixed the problem causing this error:

> Error: node_modules/@types/ws/index.d.ts:328:18 - error TS2315: Type 'Server' is not generic.

I also upgraded TypeScript to the latest 4.x.y version, per the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=15.0-16.0)'s recommendation:

```bash
npm i typescript@^4
```

I'll hold off on TS 5 until Angular upgrade guide suggests it for the next version.